# Plot curve involving integral of $\sin(x^2)$

Tags: geometry

I need to plot the curve

$$p(u)=(\sqrt{\pi} \int_0^u \cos(\frac{\pi v^2}{2}) dv,\sqrt{\pi} \int_0^u \sin(\frac{\pi v^2}{2} )dv).$$

The problem is that $\sin(x^2)$ does not have a closed form. How could I plot this curve? If it helps I have already proven that the absolute value of the curvature of this curve at any point is the same as the arc length from the origin to this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are closed form in terms of [Fresnel integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral).

$$p(u)=\big(\sqrt{\pi }\, C(u),\sqrt{\pi }\, S(u)\big)$$

which produce a nice curve.

Comment: Thank you! Can you tell me why it is $C(u),S(u)$? Because of the $\pi/2$ in the $\cos,\sin$ that's not in the Wikipedia definition?

Comment: @MagneSeier  Have a look at https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FresnelIntegrals.html (equations (3) and (4)).